# xml parser error in notepadv1 tutorial

Tags: java, android, xml, notepad

I am working on the notpadv1 tutorial.  I get an error from the parser as soon as I create a new xml file called note_row.xml and put in the following code:


The error is at the end of the file.  It says: multiple annotations found at this line
premature end of file
error parsing XML:no element found

I also see the following error in the console:
[2010-07-04 05:34:32 - Notepadv1] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

I am following the instructions in step 5 of the following url:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

Comment: Can you post the XML?  What happens when you copy and paste the XML from the website into Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in one of your XML resource files, such as a layout. It is impossible to say, from the error information you have shown here, where exactly your problem lies. There should be a line prior to the one you show in the console that would explain to you which file has a problem and what the problem is. If not, examine your files in Eclipse and look for warning or error squiggles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  The issue was with the file type.  I created a regular file, while I needed a xml file.  Instead of file > new , I used file > new > other then selected xml.  That fixed it.  I need to be able to make better sense of the error messages.  If you can suggest a document, or tutorial I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird error, yet not able to find the rootCause. But whenever this happens,

I cut my xml code from file, save it;
Then paste whole code back in file, and save it again. Error goes away.
I don't even consider this a solution. But it works.

A link to [THIS THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25928505/609782) may help.