# Android / Eclipse / Premature end of xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Let me start by acknowledging that I did find a similar question on here but there was only one answer and that answer did not apply in my situation, so...

I am just now wading into Android and have come upon a sticking point.  I am using Eclipse and have run into a problem trying to create a state-list drawable and keep getting a "premature end of file" error in Eclipse.  I have the images in my "drawable" directory.  I create a new file, name it date.xml, and type the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dategrey" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/datewhite" />
</selector>
```

The exact error that I am getting is "Premature end of file.  Error parsing XML: No elements found.".  The has me confused as there is clearly an element in there.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? What is throwing the "Premature EOF" error? Where are you seeing the error message? A screenshot may help here more than words.

Comment: The errors show up in Eclipse after I finish typing the file.  If you are familiar with Eclipse you know that you will get a notification of errors, usually a red circle with an "x" on the lines where the errors are found.  You click the circle and it gives you the errors.  You also have, on the right column, red and yellow markers at the lines where there are errors or warnings, and the top of the file will show a box that is green if the file is usable and red if it is not.  In this case it is red.  The errors occur on the line below my last line of code.  Click circle, get error messages.

Comment: OK, that helps. My next suggestion would be to ask if the above posted code is actually 100% purely copied from the file that is in Eclipse. Sounds like a "duh" question, but when other options fail, you gotta question the basics. The error indicates a syntax problem, which isn't evident in the above code.

Comment: That's a legit question.  I'm not offended by it at all.  I've been on your side of the fence on questions about other technologies so it's cool.  But the answer is yes, it is spot on what is in the file.  I've checked and rechecked this thing over and over.  Eclipse simply refuses to accept it and I honestly have no idea where the issue could be.

Comment: I even went so far as to change the file name from date.xml to dated.xml thinking that "date.xml" might somehow be reserved somewhere.  Silly, I know.  But when you get stuck in this spot long enough the silly ideas start to seem rational.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And I solved it.  Man, what a goofy thing to have confound me for two days!  I cleaned the project, rebuilt the xml file, and it works fine.  I have no idea what was plugging things up as I had never actually tried to run the project so there should not have been an issue with out.out, but it worked.  Thanks to all who offered advice.  I truly do appreciate your time and attention in helping me with this one.

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Really strange that recreating the XML file under a different name didn't fix the problem. That's just wrong.

Comment: Lol such a brilliant answer (y)

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174327/xml-parser-error-in-notepadv1-tutorial/3180155#3180155).

That person's problem was that the file was not created as an XML file, from Eclipse's point of view. Try File > New > Other... / select XML.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case as well, but creating the xml file via Eclipse in exactly the manner you suggested produced the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dategrey" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/datewhite" />
</selector>
```

You need to check the state first then call the specific drawable.

Comment: That would be strange... XML consumers are not supposed to care about the order of attributes.

Comment: You are right the order of the attributes is not important. However, the order of the entries is important when dealing with drawables.

Comment: Checking state first had no effect.  I copied and pasted what you had above and still get the premature end of file and parsing xml errors.

Comment: Have look at [this blog post](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/55) on drawables. It might help you get a better understanding of how the XML structure should look. I have a feeling that could be the problem in your case.

Comment: @Andrei: Re: "but the order of the entries is important" - but the order of items in your suggestion is the same is what the OP had. Am I missing something?? Also, order of entries may affect drawable behavior, but should not cause XML parsing errors.

Comment: I appreciate the link as it will come in handy in improving my design abilities, but there is absolutely nothing there that answers my question.  My XML is well-formed even by the examples in the link.  I have looked at countless android tutorials and examples on how to make a state-list drawable and each one uses the exact form and syntax that I have used.  I read the entire link that you posted twice and found absolutely nothing that was helpful in this situation.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Confusing, but it was an out xml file causing the issue. The name was similar so i did not notice it was actually a completely different file game_layout_out.xml.
Delete the out file and youre fine.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error using PhoneGap.

> New >> Project >> Android Project from Existing Code
>
> Then Next and Browse project and **LEAVE BLANK** copy projects into workspace and Finish.

There you go !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the new xml file in res/layout folder....and done...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just removed this line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Saved, built, then re-added it again and it was fine

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: I added a new line at the end the file, saved the XML file, and then removed that recently added line.

That trivial operation solved my problem with the XML file.

Answer (score -1):

Is `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` alive?

The XML editor will try to download the XML Schema to validate the XML. If the site is down or the XML schema is damaged, this could cause these errors.

Try to download the schema and add it to your "xml catalogue" (search in your Eclipse preferences) to avoid this problem.

Comment: Are you thinking of the `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute? The namespace URI for the `android` namespace (to which the root element does not belong) is not a URL for an XML schema for the document.

Comment: Well, it's a URI but I've had trouble with some XML parsers trying to download it. Also the URI might be mapped to a valid URL in your XML catalog.

Comment: An XML parser that tries to download every namespace URI declared in the document? And then throws an error if it can't? Something is seriously wrong with any XML parser that behaves that way.